# Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS compatible with Lenovo Yoga X1 4gen?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, suspend, lenovo, compatibility

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my new Lenovo Yoga X1 4th generation and it has many problems. For example, waking up from suspend, you often get a fresh new screen with all the programs closed as if the computer was restarted. The sound control is not working etc...

I would therefore like to know whether Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS is still compatible with the 4th generation of X1. Would you recommend me to downgrade the OS to 16.04? It seems that 18.04 still has severe problems and is not yet a stable system.

Best,
Ivan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: I can run 16.04.5 LTS on ,my 4th Gen X1 carbon Thinkpad, FWIW. I know the Yoga is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: I would prefer an answer by somebody who actually has the Yoga X1 4gen and tried which distribution is the most stable one. I know that I can create a bootable USB and try different versions, but I takes quite a while of use to discover all the possible problems that occur. So it would be nice to hear about experience from people that have used it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

A solution: I have installed the most recent version of Ubuntu (19.10) and it seems to be stable apart from minor problems like the sound control not working. I'll let you know if I encounter any serious problems after a while.